How do you use elevation in KivyMD to elevate a rounded icon button?
I just can't seem to make this work in my KivyMD project. I have read the documentation several times but I can't figure out how to get it how I want. This my python code:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivymd.uix.behaviors import CommonElevationBehavior, CircularRippleBehavior
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
Window.size = (375, 812)

class LoginWindow(MDScreen):
    pass

class MainWindow(MDScreen):
    pass

class PlayerWindow(MDScreen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class CircularElevationButton(CommonElevationBehavior, CircularRippleBehavior, 

ButtonBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
        pass

class myMusicApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file('myMusicApp.kv')
        return kv
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myMusicApp().run()

And this is my .kv file:
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    MainWindow:
    PlayerWindow:

<LoginWindow>:
    name: 'login'
    Button:
        text: 'Log in'
        on_release: app.root.current = 'player'

<MainWindow>:
    name: 'main'

<CircularElevationButton>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "100dp", "100dp"
    radius: self.size[0] / 2
    shadow_radius: self.radius[0]
    md_bg_color: "red"

    MDIcon:
        icon: "hand-heart"
        halign: "center"
        valign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        font_size: root.size[0] * .6
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: "white"

<PlayerWindow>:
    name: 'player'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout
            size_hint: 1, .06
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            MDIconButton:
                anchor_x: 'left'
                anchor_y: 'middle'
                icon: 'arrow-left'
                style: 'standard'
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Now Playing'
                halign: 'center'
                font_name: 'Roboto'
            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'menu'
        Image:
            id: 'playerImage'
            source: '/Users/name/Desktop/codingProjects/kivy/myNewApp3/ab67616d0000b273715973050587fe3c93033aad.jpeg'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, .15
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: '10dp'
            padding: '10dp'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                CircularElevationButton:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
                    elevation: 4
                    shadow_softness: 4
                

This is how it's supposed to look according to the documentation:

And this is how my result looks. There is no visible elevation and the icon size (font_size) can't be changed. Changing the elevation number does nothing either.


I believe you need to use ButtonElevationBehaviour instead of CommonElevationBehavior. Try replacing:
class CircularElevationButton(CommonElevationBehavior, CircularRippleBehavior, ButtonBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
        pass

with:
class CircularElevationButton(ButtonElevationBehaviour, CircularRippleBehavior, MDIconButton):
    pass

And adding MDIconButton simplifies the use of an icon.
